# Are class level variables/objects acceptable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple web site built with asp.net.  It typically only has 1 or 2 users at one time.  My question is, is it ok to instantiate a class at the class level or should I be instantiating for each method.  Here is an example.  I have a class named Host with a name field and mac field.  In my code behind for a specific page Is it ok to do this:

```
public partial class addhosts : Page
{
     private Host host = new Host();
     private HostDal dal = new HostDal();

     protected void myMethod()
     {
          host.Name = "myname"
          host.Mac = "mymac"
     }

     protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          dal.AddHost(host)
     }
}
```

Comment: depends how you want it to behave!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you are referring to are more typically referred to as `global` versus `local` variables.

In the simple case that you have listed, it would be better to create the variable on the submit click. The reason is if a user loads the object, but never calls the submit click, then you have instantiated the host object in memory when there was no need.

However, as many have said, it should not *really* matter one way or the other here. But, again, this is a simplistic example. Global variables can be dangerous and are often avoided as they can be modified from anywhere in your class. If one method expects a certain value that is then overrode, this can cause difficult to debug issues in more complex examples

[Here is a wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable) that reiterates my above point:

> They are usually considered bad practice precisely because of their
>   non-locality: a global variable can potentially be modified from
>   anywhere (unless they reside in protected memory or are otherwise
>   rendered read-only), and any part of the program may depend on it

To get rid of the globals, you could do this (using object initializers)

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var host = new Host
          {
              Name = "myname",
              Mac = "mymac"
          };
      dal.AddHost(host)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize this is a simple example.  I guess a better question would have been is this bad practice.  How else could I get the host information into the sumbit method If I instantiated it inside of a different method?

Comment: If you don't mind can throw in one more wrench.  Lets say on page load I read in the host from a database, then assign host.Name to a text box, a user can change the name and then on submit send host back to the database.  Using your suggestion I would need to instantiate or initialize host 2 different times,once in page load and once in submit,  is that correct?.  It just seems to make more sense to do it one time and change the values as needed.  Thanks again.

Comment: But, keep in mind that HTML is stateless (ASP bastardizes it to make it seem stateful), so you are going to instantiate the object twice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't matter.

Each request to your page is separate and has no knowledge of other requests therefore there is no chance of there being a "conflict" with other requests.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely OK to have user specific data as fields inside an ASP.Net Page instance.  Every visit to a page creates a new instance of the `Page` class hence you'll not end up in a situation where data is incorrectly shared between users

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine, since for each user new class is created (ASP.NET by design). It's in separate thread also, so even static variables would be acceptable in this scenario.

Cheers, Ivan

Comment: Are you sure about this? I'm not going to rustle up a test page but Static variables are accessible between different threads and in general I would expect that if you stored somethign in a static variable that a different session would be able to pick it up...

Comment: No where did icesar or the OP say that the variable was static! Static variables are a different beast and persist across the entire application pool. In the OPs example, every time a request comes in for the addhost page a new instance of that class gets created. The variables are at the class level and thus each user request has it's own instance.

Comment: "so even static variables would be acceptable in this scenario" - icesar.  That line is not true.